# void function in a function parameter

Tags: c++

In my data structure textbook, there's a function (a member function of a class ADT tree, array based) looking like this:

```
void preorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const   // ItemType is a template
```

where in all sample code files, visit() is not defined. Suppose I need to define the visit() myself, what does a function in a function's parameter mean?

in case it's needed, The preorderTraverse() function should be a recursive function that traverses its left child-tree and right-child tree. Does the void visit() help to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Your visit function would simply look like

```
void myVisit(ItemType &item)
```

A function as a parameter just means that you can pass a custom "callback" function, which in this case presumably gets called at each step of the preorder traversal.

It doesn't really matter that it's a "void" function; `preorderTraverse` is just going to call it.

Comment: my question is, it is a void function so it does not return anything. How can that be a argument of another function?

Comment: @Partita it doesn't need to return a value because the visit function parameter is a pointer. it is operating on the array directly.

Comment: @Partita To be clear, `myVisit(item)` would have no value, it would be an expression of type `void`, and you're right that that would not be a valid function argument. You cannot write `preorderTraverse(myVisit(item))`. But `myVisit` itself *isn't* an expression of type `void`. It is an expression of type "function taking `ItemType` by reference and returning nothing". That's something another function can work with. You'd call it as `preorderTraverse(myVisit)`.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation. Another question emerges: how can I refer to the argument in the preorderTraverse() function? Suppose I have a member array, and I need to check if mem_arr[i] == 0 .

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of using `void visit()` is to perform some sort of operation on all the nodes, and is separate from simply traversing the tree by `preorderedTraverse`, which would traverse the tree and perform `visit()` on all the nodes.

For example if our tree was contating int values keyed by string (name, age): `struct PersonNode {std::string name; int age;};`, and we would like to simulate a passing year we would write a function:

```
void myVisit(PersonNode &node) {
    node.age++;
}
```

And we would use `void preorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&)) const` like so:

```
tree.predorderTraverse(myVisit);
```

And it would perform the action contained in myVisit in all the nodes in a tree.

Simpler example would be:

```
void myVisit(PersonNode &node) {
    std::cout << node.name << "'s age :" << node.age;
}
```

and

```
tree.predorderTraverse(myVisit);
```

would print all the nodes.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation. Another question emerges: how can I refer to the argument in the preorderTraverse() function? Suppose I have a member array, and I need to check if mem_arr[i] == 0. should I use node (as it is in the myVist() )?

Comment: That's an interesting question (if I get it well). Could you elaborate a bit on the implementation of preorderTraverse() and the whole data structure? Seeing as you use an array to store abstract tree type.

Answer (score 0):

A function invokation is different than a function.  Stop thinking of functions as `f(x)` -- they are just `f`.

You can then invoke the function `f` by passing it arguments like `f(x)`.

Now the syntax `void f(int)` gives the signature and return value of your function `f` -- it returns nothing, and can be invoked with a single `int`.

In your case:

```
void preorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&))
```

`visit` is a parameter.  It must be a function that can be invoked with an `ItemType&`, and return nothing.

`preorderTraverse` takes as one argument a function of type `visit` described above (actually an anonymous type, but whatever).

So you write:

```
void my_function(ItemType& i){
  std::cout << "boo!\n";
}
```

then call the traverse with:

```
obj.preorderTraverse(my_function);
```

and `obj` can use your `my_function` within its body, probably calling it on each element in the tree.